# How to add/assign or change featured image in post programmatically?

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, automation

I have written a plugin that (besides other functionality) makes posts from existing content. For each post I have one picture - **how to make them featured programmatically**?

I do the:

```
$id =  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
wp_set_object_terms( $id, $cat_ids, 'category' );
```

and I would like my next step to be inserting $image (file path or URI) as featured image. How?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [**`set_post_thumbnail()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail).

Assuming you already know how to determine the `$post` (ID or object) for which to set the featured image, and the `$thumbnail_id` (ID) of the image that you want to set as the featured image:

```
set_post_thumbnail( $post, $thumbnail_id );
```

Comment: Chip, thanks very much, I've assumed that such function exists, but how do I get $thumbnail_id which is integer, and I've expected file path or URL string?

Answer (score 3):

[set_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail) will allow to set 1 attachment from id to a post of provided id.

If you don't have the attachment id or want to do it directly from url, you will have to create the attachment first, see [wp_insert_attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment)

you may also upload the image using [media_sideload_image](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/media_sideload_image)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [wp_insert_attachment()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_attachment) and [wp_generate_attachment_metadata()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_generate_attachment_metadata) to make the image an attachment to the post.
And you make it a featured image by using [set_post_thumbnail()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail). (it's really just a custom field _thumbnail_id.
Something like:

```
$attach_id   = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $filename, $post_id );
$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $filename );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id,  $attach_data );
set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Featured images programmatically .

```
function setFeaturedImages() {

$base = dirname(__FILE__);
$imgfile= $base.DS.'images'.DS.'14'.DS.'Ascot_Anthracite-Grey-1.jpg';
$filename = basename($imgfile);
$upload_file = wp_upload_bits($filename, null, file_get_contents($imgfile));
if (!$upload_file['error']) {
    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_parent' => 0,
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', $filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
$attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload_file['file'], 209 );

if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $upload_file['file'] );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id,  $attachment_data );
}

set_post_thumbnail( 209, $attachment_id );

}
```

}

Please refer the tutorial for detailed explanation.
http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/insert-udpate-wordpress-post-programmatically/